# <p:ajax listener> not working on event change but working onload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userModel.country}" required="true" >
      <c:selectItem itemValue="Select Country"/>
      <c:selectItem itemValue="USA"/>
      <c:selectItem itemValue="Canada"/>
      <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" listener="#{usdc.countryChange()}"/></h:selectOneMenu>
```

This ajax listener is called when the page is loaded but not when the item is selected. The bean is viewscoped.

Secondly I have to call the function like listener="#{usdc.countryChange()}" and not listener="#{usdc.countryChange}". If I remove the parentheis I get the error such a field is not defined. Here is schema declaration:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">`
```

Comment: Switch to `p:selectOneMenu` (you are using a PrimeFaces Ajax handler).

Comment: @JasperDeVries: if the listener is called when the page is loaded (it should NOT be) there most likely is a problem of the `p:ajax` not being renderd/recognised at all (PF not included correctly) and the listener not being a listener but EL as plain text...

Comment: Well.. a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Well Kukeltje, you may be right since <f:ajax> is working as expected. But what could be missing . I have added the dependecy primefaces-6.1.jar in my classpath.

Comment: Maybe the dependency is not deployed? Search google/stackoverflow for issues related to this.

Comment: Your 'secondly' error is a confirmation of my first comment...